Multi-positional one-hot encoding based update
I have some array, and a given index/array of indices. Using this index/indices, I have to update another array. These updates shouldn't be in-place. I am able to do this for a single index, but unable to achieve the right result for array of indices. Here is an example:
def one_hot(x, depth):
  return np.take(np.eye(depth), x, axis=0)

arr1 = np.random.rand(2, 5, 3, 8)
ohe_depth = 5

# Case 1: Single index based OHE op
curr_idx = np.array([1])
curr_idx_ohe = one_hot(curr_idx, ohe_depth).reshape(1, ohe_depth, 1, 1)
out = arr1 * curr_idx_ohe # produces right output

# Case 2: Multi index based OHE op
curr_idx = np.arange(3)
curr_idx_ohe = one_hot(curr_idx, ohe_depth)

# What should be the transformation here that is equivalent to:
# out2 = np.zeros_like(arr1)
# out2[:, curr_idx, ...] = arr1[:, curr_idx, ...]


Again, no in-place updates are allowed. TIA.

Your first case produces an array out where, for the axis with size 5, all values are 0.0 except along the index where curr_idx is 1.0. I'm not sure how to generalize to multiple curr_idx. For instance, in the second case, does that mean you conceptually want 3 such arrays stacked into an out2 array with one more dimension? What is the  desired output shape, depending on the shape of the input?

This is the desired output out2[:, curr_idx, ...] = arr1[:, curr_idx, ...]

Can you please provide the implementation for this alternative?

Can curr_idx have duplicate indices?

No, it's more like a sequence starting from 0 to a certain length

The best I can think of is curr_idx_ohe = one_hot(curr_idx, ohe_depth).any(axis=0).reshape(1, ohe_depth, 1, 1), out2 = arr1 * curr_idx_ohe?

doesn't reshape(curr_idx.size, ohe_depth, 1, 1) just work?
